# pdfpages: \includepdf does load pdf file without signature image

Tags: graphics, pdf, pdfpages

I have an instruction-document from my university, which I need to sign with my signature and include at the beginning of my Latex-Document.
As proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739159/inserting-a-pdf-file-in-latex
I added `\includepdf[pages={-}]{instruction.pdf}` after the `\maketitle`.
It loads the document just fine, but without my signature. In all pdf-viewers on my PC, as well as in LibreOffice Writer, it shows the file with my signature. But includepdf only loads the text without the signature image to my Latex document. How to handle this?

**Edit:** I did covert the .pdf file to a .png and included that, even if it is now low resolution, thanks to converting, I got the signature in my document. Still wondering about the crazy behaviour of pdfpages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you mean a PDF digital signature? Or an included picture of your signature?

Comment: An included picture of my signature. I took the instruction document to a friends IPad, signed it there and he send the resulting pdf, with my signature on it, back to me.

Comment: you probably added an annotation. Such annotations are stripped when you include them as graphic. Can you flatten the pdf?

Comment: One approach to flatten the PDF is to print it into a new PDF with annotations, so in the print menu select document and annotations.

Answer (score 0):

As already said in the comments, this happens because iPadOS adds the scribbled content as annotations (which is quite useful IMO), and `pdfpages` seems to ignore those.

Along the lines of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1762125/706075), here's a solution that helped me:

1. Open the PDF with the signature in a browser (**not** *Preview*!)
2. Try to print it from the browser, but instead of the printer, choose “Print to PDF”
3. When you click “Print”, it will download the PDF. The annotations will be flattened, and the signature will be seen in the final document